# How can I download a youtube audio via python script in windows

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I am building a program in python and I need to download an audio from a youtube video.

I searched on google and I found that there is a package called `youtube-dl`, but it has only an interpreter and I need to use it in code.

So I continued looking and I found out that you can't use this in code in windows, only in linux.

Is there another way to download audio from youtube video?

May I use `youtube-dl` module in a python program?

Comment: From the README (https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/): `Windows users can download an .exe file and place it in any location on their PATH except for %SYSTEMROOT%\System32 (e.g. do not put in C:\Windows\System32).` -- I don't understand the problem. Why can't you use the `exe` in your code, in Windows?

Comment: @TomLord I tried... Its not working, I added the .exe path to my PATH and then when i write in my code: import youtube_dl its not recognizing it.

Comment: Please, always, include your code/config/errors in the original post. You will get a *much* better response by providing all of the appropriate information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [developer section](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl) and  [the installation instructions](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#installation) for Windows.

Comment: I tried... Its not working, I added the .exe path to my PATH and then when i write in my code: import youtube_dl its not recognizing it.

Comment: Did you install it via pip or easy_install @fmmw774

Comment: Thank you! I used pip and it worked! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Thats great! Mark the answer as correct so other people can check it if they have the same problem :) @fmmw774

Comment: Marked! I really appreaciate your help!